# How to do a copy constructor for an object without members

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have an object that has not members (except for 2 `enums`):

```
class Displayer
{
public:
  Displayer();
  ~Displayer();

  enum FlagShowRF { NONE, RCTS, CNTRS, BOTH };
  enum FlagDisplay { NOT_DISPLAY, DISPLAY };

  void displayImg(const cv::Mat& image, const std::string& name, FlagDisplay flg);
  void displayImg(const cv::Size& sz, const RegFil& rf,
                  const std::string& name, FlagShowRF flg);
  void displayImg(const KeyPointVector& kpts, const cv::Mat& image,
                  const std::string& name, FlagDisplay flg);
  void displayImg(const std::vector<KeyPointVector>& kptsGroups,
                 const cv::Mat& img, const std::string& name, FlagDisplay flg);

  void closeAllWindows();
};
```

Is it ok to have a copy constructor? If yes, how would it be? I thought of:

```
  Displayer(const Displayer& displayer) { *this = displayer; }
```

Or how shall I do it?

Comment: Don't do anything. The compiler will make one for you that does the appropriate thing (nothing much.)

Comment: Even if I have declared a no-parameters constructor?

Comment: Yes. But remove that one too! And the destructor. And then think carefully about whether you really need a class.

Comment: It seems that it has done it even if I did not remove the two (ctor and dctor)

Comment: Right, but you don't need those anyway, so you?

Comment: How about removing all constructors and destructors, then changing `class` keyword to `namespace`?

Comment: OTOH when your class is an ABC, you declare the copy constructor and the copy assignment deleted.

Comment: Why should I use a `namespace` and not a `class`?

Comment: Why do you *need* a class?